# Wifi driver for hp 14-G008AU

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, atheros

i'm installing ubuntu 14.04 on my HP 14-G008AU, and it seems that wifi is not detected. Can anyone help me to resolve this problem? Thanks

Comment: **Can you identify the Wi-Fi chipset (or device)?** Check details from **`lsusb`** (for USB vendor, device ID) and **`sudo lshw`** (for hardware details).

Comment: I expect if uses: **Ralink 802.11b/g/n** However, HP also has WiFi modules from Realtek, Atheros, and Broadcom for the **HP 14** (aka **HP 240 G1/G3**) Notebook.

Comment: @david6 thanks for you clue mate. it was atheros ar9565. and I found the answer in [http://askubuntu.com/questions/215498/how-to-install-qualcomm-atheros-ar9565-wireless-drivers]. it works

Comment: It seems odd that there is no workaround, as downloading an *additional driver* (from some 'trusted' site) is almost never a long term fix (or *really* recommended).