# Wifi keeps going out

Tags: wireless, 16.04, laptop

I just updated to 16.04LTS five days ago, and now, starting today, my laptop will disconnect from my wireless network and say "device not ready" when I click the network drop down. The only way it is resolved is when I restart my laptop. Please help.

lspci | grep Wireless gives:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

rfkill gives:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
     Soft blocked: yes
     Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `lspci | grep Wireless` (CaSe sensitive)

Comment: this question may be useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/215498/how-to-install-qualcomm-atheros-ar9565-wireless-drivers

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` terminal command.